# Sql Statement(if (@companyCode is not null) set @companyCode = '%' + @companyCode + '%')?

Tags: sql

what is the meaning of below sql statement i mean what it saying?

```
if (@companyCode is not null) set @companyCode = '%' + @companyCode + '%'
if (@companyName is not null) set @companyName = '%' + @companyName + '%'
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is checking whether the variable or parameter `@companyCode` contains the value `NULL` or not.

It is necessary to use `IS NULL` for this rather than `=NULL` because normal equality comparisons don't work with `NULL` (`NULL = NULL` does not evaluate to true. )

If it is not null then a percentage sign is appended either side and the result reassigned to the variable.

The `+` is the string concatenation operator in TSQL as opposed to `||` used in other dialects.

Presumably this is to be used in a [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) query where `%` is a wildcard character meaning match any set of 0 or more characters. These `LIKE` searches with leading wildcards are expensive as they cannot take advantage of an index in finding rows that meet the expression. Full text indexing can often help this sort of need.

The check for null isn't really needed because if `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` is on (the default) then the result of the concatenation will still be `NULL` anyway.

The same for the second line but different variable obviously.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable @companyCode is not set to null value then modify the variable by adding % at the beginning and the end. 
Do the same with the @companyName variable.

Comment: Thank you Ricky.Is there any reason for do like this?

Comment: I think what the code implies is that the variable is going to be used in a select later. Like "if a company name is entered, search for any company that matches that name". For example: you enter "roso", it gets translated to "%roso%" and matches "Microsoft" and "Peligroso Inc"

Answer (score 0):

This means:

if value in `@companyCode` parameter is not `db-NULL`, set value `@companyCode` to the `'%' + @companyCode + '%'`